# How to take screenshots with a timestamp and date stamp (with scrot command)

Tags: scrot-command

How to take screenshots with a timestamp and date stamp (with scrot command)? I forget the dates and i dont have time to go to properties and see the date. also, dates aren't written on the panel even! i use lubuntu 13.10 and 512 mb ram

Answer (score 1):

Because `scrot` automatically names the files according to the date on my Lubuntu I think you are not looking for the filename to be the date but to put the date in the picture.

If you want the date to be shown on the panel in Lubuntu:

1. Right click on the clock in the panel and select *"Digital Clock" Settings*.
2. Edit *Clock Format* so it reads `%x %R` .
3. Close that window.

If you want some other date formatting just look up the available options in `man strftime`.

[image]

Or to append the date to a picture you can install `imagemagick` with `sudo apt-get install imagemagick` and then use `scrot` with the following command:

```
scrot -e 'convert $f label:"%x %X" -append $f'
```

This command will append the date below the picture. If you want it to be somewhere else in the picture, in other size, or overlapping the picture, etc. please lookup the documentation of `imagemagick` and modify the above command accordingly. To modify simply the date format refer again to `man sfrtime` and change `"%x %X"` accordingly.